# raspberry pi zero: send digital system sound to GPIO

Tags: audio

I've used linux daily for a few years, I've heard a lot of talk about pulseaudio/pipewire, etc. Sounds very complicated.

What I want to do is use a raspberry pi zero, and send the digital system sound over to the GPIO pins. I was hoping there was a file somewhere in Debian which was just a constant stream of instantaneous amplitude of the system sound.

So how does one go about piping or extracting the system sound?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: I think you mean you're looking for a sound driver which uses the gpio pins to output digital audio. Is that correct? If so, i2s outer some other digital format?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, actually I'm not really interested in the Pi side of things yet, or using the GPIO pins. I'm wondering if it's possible to peek into the real-time system sound of a linux OS. When you press play on an audio file, I have no idea what the system is actually doing, the streams etc. Thanks!

Comment: That depends on what plays and how. But your question actually already contains the knowledge. Some client (e.g., your media player) sends samples to a sound server (e.g., pipewire), which in turn talks to the Linux audio driver framework (ALSA), which has drivers for the actual audio hardware. So, it's not quite clear what you mean with "peek into…", at which point you want to. But the good news is, every single of these layers has some form of monitor capability with which you can observe the multiple streams. So, the answer to the questio "is it possible" is *YES!*. *Where* and *how* to

Comment: poke around depends on what you want to do. Now, is that your RPi GPIO thing, or was that just a decoy and should be marked as such? to illustrate: the possible answers range from "yeah just use the monitor offered to you by your pipewire, that's a full click away" to "… and then you compile the new kernel module and load it, and modify the hardware definitions in your device tree to make Linux assign the right hardware resources to your newly-written driver".

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Thanks for the reply. My idea was that I could write a programme which would run on boot and which could read a piece of memory (I guess related to ALSA) for whatever the HDMI or audio jack would see, and then output that data to the GPIO pins. My background is that I did C at uni as part of an Electrical Eng degree, but I'm not a programmer. Cheers

Comment: That's not how the involved hardware works, so that specifically is impossible (and not because of Linux), and it's also not wie clear what that would be, considering the complexity of the way audio is embedded in the HDMI data stream. But as said, you could just have a hardware driver that takes the same data that gets sent to the GPU peripheral, and converts that to a format that could be output via gpio. By the way, "I'm an electrical engineer, not a programmer", I'm an electrical engineer as well. When working with embedded computers, that's the skill you need.

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller, not possible because this isn't the way the digital data packets can be converted to analogue output, or some other reason? I'll be honest, using digital PWM for output seems pretty strange. I've done power electronics, but from what I recall PWM switching was more about inductors in continuous conduction. Did you have a driver in mind, which can be used to take the GPU peripheral data and convert it? Any advantage of doing that rather than skimming it from ALSA or PuleAudio? I'm more interested in ease than eloquence. (I am only used to Debian derived distros) Thanks

Comment: Where does pwm suddenly appear from? I'm confused. Is that the representation of the audio you want to use?! Very confused. Again, the data for the GPU can't be used like that, but the audio before it gets handed to the audio driver for the HDMI output can.

Comment: And to repeat what I said: if you just want access to the audio, yeah, just use the monitor channel that your pipe wire, pulse or alsa offer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry for the lack of context regarding PWM, this was because there is no analogue output GPIO pins on the Pi. From quick googling this looks like it's called DirectStreamDigital. I don't want to write an audio driver, so any idea how one would access the audio channel of a monitor? P.S. apprantly HDMI uses PulseCodeModulation, which seems use 16 bit amplitudes. Ether way I'd be happy to be able to output PCM or DSD to the GPIOs. Thanks

Comment: Dsd is something different again. Can we not introduce something new every comment. You are misunderstanding what pcm is, as well, and again, and this is the last time I repeat that, you don't get access to what is inside the HDMI transport. Say, clearly, what you want, instead of guessing based on hastily researched buzzwords. You are an electrical engineer, act like one! What is the technical thing you want to build? What are the requirements for that? "GPIO" literally just says "General purpose interface", so it's up to you to define what kind of signal you need. Start with analog or

Comment: digital, and if digital, synchronous or asynchronous, parallel or serial interface, and if you actually have a standard that you definitely need to adhere to, that. Please don't guess, specify correctly.

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller, sorry for the frustration. The reason I left it at 'GPO' is because I can build a (clock if it's synchronous) DAC, filter, amplifier as required and the first step is understanding what the data is that I have to work with. I.e. what is being handed to the audio driver from ALSA, and how can I access it.  I'm not specifying the standard because I don't have any control on if the data type or protocol, it's not up to me to define, I have to work with whatever it already is as defined by the OS audio framework. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Your confusing things. It's the audio driver who defines how the samples are converted to electrical signals at the gpio pins by the hardware. So, yes, you have control over that. That's the point of a driver.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution lies in Device Tree Overlays .

Modifying `/boot/config.txt` to reconfigure the pins at boot,

```
dtoverlay=pwm loads the driver e.g.
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,pin=18,func=2,pin2=13,func2=4
```

or

```
dtoverlay=pwm,pin=18,func=2
```

That would enable PWM on GPIO 18 (pin 12). Then the magic starts... you should see a `/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/` directory with various files in. If you write `0` to the `export` file, it will create `pwm0`. In `pwm0` you will find more files like `enable`, `period` and `duty_cycle` which you can write the values you need to.

I believe this works with C and python (I've never used python).

More research required, but there is a lot on the internet, I still need to do more research to understand the `func` etc. But there is an abundance of articles on the internet such as *Pi IoT In C Using Linux Drivers - The PWM Driver*.  (I do not condone the idea of IoT, sounds like a dystopia).